# Preorder traversal of a binary tree. If vs while

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I am trying to figure out why the console output get stuck in an infinite loop at the leaf when I use while in place of if in the code below.

```
void preOrder(Node root) {
    Node n = root;
    while(n != null) {
        visit(n);
        preOrder(n.left);
        preOrder(n.right);
        }
    }
```

When the recursive function for preOrder is called at the leaf, the leaf has no left child.Shouldn't the execution stop there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when having `while(n != null)`, you never reassign `n` to something that could potentially be not `null` and thus you get an infinite loop.

An `if` statement is what you need, because you already have recursive calls, which will traverse the tree up until a leaf is found:

```
Node n = root;
if (n != null) {
    visit(n);
    preOrder(n.left);
    preOrder(n.right);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`while(n != null)` will either always be true or never be true, since the body of the loop doesn't change the value of `n`. Therefore, the loop will either never execute or be infinite.

Since you are using recursion, you don't need a loop.

```
void preOrder(Node root) {
    Node n = root;
    if (n != null) {
        visit(n);
        preOrder(n.left);
        preOrder(n.right);
    }
}
```

> When the recursive function for preOrder is called at the leaf, the leaf has no left child.Shouldn't the execution stop there

Well, the execution of `preOrder(n.left)` will terminate (since `n.left` is null), but then it will return to the previous `preOrder` call, and call `preOrder(n.right)`, and if that call terminates, it will then be stuck in the infinite while loop.